# Does the Tosafot HaRosh cover all the Babylonian Talmud?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tosfot

As how the title states, does the Tosafot HaRosh cover all of the tractates of the Talmud. If it doesn't then which tractates does it cover?

Comment: See here: https://www.myseferstore.com/tosafos-harash-4-vol-med-size.html

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @N.T. I checked and for the Babylonian Talmud it includes Berakhot; all of Moed except Pesachim, Betza, Taanit, and Chagigah; all of Nashim; all of Nezikin except Bava Kamma, Bava Batra, and Makkot; for Kodashim only Khullin; and its missing Niddah. But I also found a 16 volume version that includes all of the tractates of this 4 volume version except that it is missing Sanhedrin, and it includes Chagigah, Betza, and Niddah. So are these really the only tractates for which there is Tosafot Harosh? If true then it would not exist for almost all of Kodashim and some parts of Moed and Nezikin.

Comment: We don't know how much was originally written. The question is how much was preserved. Almost all of the Tosafos HaRosh we have is based on manuscripts recently discovered.

Comment: @N.T. I suppose that's what I would like to know for now. "Which tractates of the Babylonian Talmud are covered by the surviving manuscripts of the Tosafot HaRosh?" Do you know the answer to this or should I post it as a separate question?

Comment: The tricky thing is that sometimes manuscripts are discovered, and people want to attribute them to this or that well-known author, but often the evidence is not conclusive. So one would really have to go through the introductions to know how solid the evidence of authorship is.